# Android Emulator, dynamically changing sd cards

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard, android-virtual-device

does anybody know a way to change sd cards in avd dynamically?

```
emulator -avd avd_8 -sdcard /TMP/sdcard1.img
```

the command line starts a new instance of the avd. I need to do the stuff on the running avd

Regards,
Galym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this.

The SDCard mounts on boot.  Physical devices have hardware sensors to detect insertion/removal of an SD card, which the AVD presumably cannot handle.

I haven't tried this, but you *might* be able to first unmount the SD card in the Android main menu on the emulator, and then use the avd command to remount a different one.